# Javascript/jQuery codes doesn't work... - codes on github

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, git

I'm trying to do simple things like **make a text blink** (the "*Loading... please wait.*" text) and to do a simple animation... moving the *div* **intro** to the outside top of the page along with the **body** *div* (yes, there's a div called body)

This is the *intro.js* file:

```
var blinker = function() {
  $('.loading').fadeOut(500);
  $('.loading').fadeIn(500);
}

setInterval(blinker, 1000);

var vanish = function(){
 $(document).ready( function(){
     $('.intro').animate({
         top: '-100%'
     }, 4000);
     $('.body').animate({
         top: '-100%'
     }, 4000);
 });

$(document).ready(vanish);
```

What i'm asking is how to fix this error... what's the error? Nothing happens.

*All the other files are on my git, [click here](https://github.com/Relbeits/relbeits.net) to see.*

**@dragonslovetacos already answered me how to fix the blink text.**

Now I just need to fix the code to **move the page** to the **outside** (top) of the screen. This code is to run **after the page load.**

*Fixed* - Problem solved

*Thanks for @dragonslovetacos help but I could solve the slide up code by myself (without read anything just the code).*

What I did to slide the page up was just **erase** the first line of the **vanish** code, like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
     $('.intro').animate({
         top: '-100%'
     }, 4000);
     $('.body').animate({
         top: '-100%'
     }, 4000);
 });
```

Thanks again, for everyone who answered this question, mostly to @dragonslovetacos.

~relbeits_

Comment: You should read any of the hundreds of jQuery starter tutorials available online and try again. You have some very basic mistakes here that suggest you really need to start from the beginning.

Comment: Check to see if you have errors first. Open the developer tools by hitting f12 on your browser of choice and click on the console tab. If there are no errors ensure that your js file is loading by looking at the resources tab or script tab(depends on browser). Also add debug statements such as `console.log("here");` to determine what is and is not executing.

Comment: Like Jeopardy, please rephrase this in the form of a question. Also, don't link to your entire repo and expect people to browse the code. Post the relevant bits here or at the very least, place it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't know much UX, but I'm pretty sure things that blink are considered taboo on all websites designed after 1998.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    function blink() {
        $('.loading').fadeToggle('slow', function () {
            // Done.
        });
    }

    setInterval(blink, 500);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loading">Loading...</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLN5k/)

Then to make the loading area "slide up" (along with the rest of your site) give this a try.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.loading').slideUp('fast', function(){
    // Done.
});
```

Comment: A little explanation of what you fixed would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't really fix anything - just kind of...did it. It was an easy enough question that took me literally 2 minutes to write out. But, I'm using docready & within that, I am just using setInterval on a function called "blink". Within "blink" I am just toggling the visibility.

Comment: hmm... evething still the same... 
I tried @dragonslovetacos' code but doesn't workt too...

I can't understand what's wrong with my code, yesterday everything worked fine..

Comment: There must be an error(s) somewhere else in your script file(s) then I think. The above code works; it's the same code that is in the jsFiddle

Comment: Oh thanks! I just removed the other code on the file (the code to move the page up) and now your blink code is working perfectly.

Now i just have to fix the other code to move de page up and show the website.

Comment: Oh geez! My apologies, I didn't even see that part of your question. I'll post another part for that.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for waste you time helping me.

Comment: You're very welcome - no waste at all.